# Error deploying sharepoint solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

While deploying solution I am getting following error after changing the template name in sharepoint site definition solution.

Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Cannot resolve model for the Feature with ID: 1c7016c9-7920-4140-89c9-f517a3517d0c.

Any guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to get this fixed by removing some unnecessary lits/content types which were lying without any use. also there was a problem with urls of workflow task which were too long.
hope this helps for others too.

Reference:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/0ee41ebe-f7ae-4620-ba16-362af182e130